# Mysql select distinct id's and select first row only

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

This is my table. I want to select distinct 'bill_no' with only first related row.

```
    +--------------+--------------+-------+------------+
    | id | bill_no | product_name | tax   | total      | 
    +--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+
    | 1  |    12   |   Hairgel    |  10   |        241 |      
    | 2  |    12   |  Spiker gel  |  10   |        300 |      
    | 3  |    13   | Wokzem amba  |  12   |        450 |      
    | 4  |    13   | test prod    |  1    |        145 |      
    | 5  |    14   | wokk         |  3    |         55 |   
    | 6  |    14   | Kamer hyp    |  11   |         46 |      
    | 7  |    15   | Xyombokx     |  2    |        220 |     
    +--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+
```

I want data to be displayed like the below table having only distinct "bill_no" -

**Output-**

```
    +--------------+--------------+-------+------------+
    | id | bill_no | product_name | tax   | total      | 
    +--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+
    | 1  |    12   |   Hairgel    |  10   |        241 |                
    | 3  |    13   | Wokzem amba  |  12   |        450 |           
    | 5  |    14   | wokk         |  3    |         55 |         
    | 7  |    15   | Xyombokx     |  2    |        220 |     
    +--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of the request ? What will you do with data ?

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Actually i am trying to build a billing application. Their is no master table for this. All data related to bill is stored in a single one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `group by`

```
select * from youtable group by bill_no
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select t1.* 
from your_table t1
join
(
  select min(id) as id
  from your_table
  group by bill_no
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY clause.GROUP BY clause always return first row with related group by cloumn name.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_1` group by `bill_no`
```